# Find all Sundays in mySQL between January - March, 2016

Tags: mysql, date

What query to get all the Sundays date between January - March 2016? 
so output just the shown date only.

```
|  Sundays  |
|- - - - - -| 
|    2      |
|    9      |
|    16     |
|    23     |
|    30     |
 - - - - - -
```

i find query like this `select ('2013-04-15' - interval dayofweek('2013-08-15') - 1 day) - interval (weekofyear('2013-04-15') - 1) * 7 day as SUNDAY;`
 but just shown one sunday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the Sunday below query will work for you

```
select DATE_ADD('2016-01-01', INTERVAL ROW DAY) as Date,
row+1 as DayOfMonth 
from

        (
        SELECT @row := @row + 1 as row 
        FROM 
                (
                 select 0 
                 union all 
                 select 1 
                 union all 
                 select 3 
                 union all 
                 select 4 
                 union all 
                 select 5 
                 union all 
                 select 6
                 ) t1,

                (
                 select 0 
                 union all 
                 select 1 
                 union all 
                 select 3 
                 union all 
                 select 4 
                 union all 
                 select 5 
                 union all 
                 select 6
                 ) t2, 
                (SELECT @row:=-1
                ) t3 limit 31
        ) b
where 
DATE_ADD('2016-01-01', INTERVAL ROW DAY)
between '2016-01-01' and '2016-03-31'
and
DAYOFWEEK(DATE_ADD('2016-01-01', INTERVAL ROW DAY))=1;
```

Comment: wow,, too long,, didn't have a simple query for this ? can you explain to me about row? sorry im newbie